# one of my two git accounts gives Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: bash, git, github, gitlab

I've been trying to set up my work git account in addition to the personal one, but the personal one works fine and no matter what I try with the work account it doesn't work, I went through a lot of video and articles, I am really following all the steps but still unable to make the work one work.

Here is everything I have:

inside the ~/pc.user/.SSH  folder

**config**

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.SSH/id_personal

Host gitlab.company.com
    HostName gitlab.company.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.SSH/id_company
```

Listing files in ~/.SSH

```
    $ ls ~/.SSH
config  id_company  id_company.pub  id_personal  id_personal.pub
```

I doublechecked the GitHub personal account again to make sure the key is registered there and also the company gitlab account and deleted and added the key again as a reassurance.

I have two projects on my work gitlab account
[image]

This is the url that I get from the clone button on gitlab.company.com

```
git@gitlab.company.com:shaima.mahmoud/my-test-project.git
```

Then when I move the CompanyReposFolder nad try to clone
I get this error:

```
cd ~/CompanyGitLabRepos
$ git clone git@gitlab.company.com:shaima.mahmoud/my-test-project.git
Cloning into 'my-test-project'...
ssh: connect to host gitlab.company.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also had a `~/.gitconfig`  the global config file that I removed

Comment: For whatever reason, the attempt to connect to `gitlab.company.com` is timing out. This has nothing to do with your credentials or SSH configuration.

Comment: do you mean that, I did everything correctly, who should I contact in my company to support me with this issue, is it the Help desk ?